# IE10 table-layout:fixed broken if colspan is used

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-10

The following HTML renders perfectly in all common browsers including IE7-9 but fails in IE10. Even when running IE10 in compatibility mode, it fails.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:500px">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:100px" ></col>
            <col ></col>
            <col style="width:100px" ></col>
            <col ></col>
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div style="background:red;"> red </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div style="background:green;"> green </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

While in all other browsers the 2 cells are equal in size, on IE10 (at least when running on Windows7) the first cell is wider than the second.

This HTML in IE 9/Windows 7:

[image: In IE 9]

Same HTML in IE 10/Windows 7:

[image: In IE 10]

Testpage: http://www.dinkypage.com/167605

Reported Bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781009/ie-10-fails-to-render-tables-width-fixed-layout-correctly

Does anyone know solution/workaround for this problem?

UPDATE: I asked Microsoft to re-open my reported bug because it's a violation of the w3c standard. The answer is:

> "The issue you are reporting is by design. Internet Explorer only uses the first set of TD tags to set the width for a column.".

The w3c standard (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) says:

> In the fixed table layout algorithm, the width of each column is determined as follows:
>
> 1. A column element with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property sets the width for that column.
> 2. Otherwise, a cell in the first row with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property determines the width for that column. If the cell spans more than one column, the width is divided over the columns.
> 3. Any remaining columns equally divide the remaining horizontal table space (minus borders or cell spacing).

That means, this function is broken by design in IE 10. I recommend to use a different browser or stay with IE 9...

Comment: Same problem exists in IE 10 on Windows 8

Comment: The problem is also there, if all <col>s have a defined width...

Comment: Just assign the styles to the `td`s in the first `tr` instead of `col`s.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Since in my app rows are added dynamically (probably the first row contains colspans), this won't solve my problem. Adding a row that contains TDs for setting the width is not an option because it would add a gap before the table.
BTW: Please post (potential) solitions as answers, not as comments

Comment: Microsoft itself states that the colgroup defines column's widths if table-layout:fixed is used - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ie/ms531161(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Microsoft unfortunately marks most bugs in Connect as "By Design" unless they plan to fix them.  They think (although this concept fails) that suggesting correctly that this [airquote]works[/airquote] "As Designed" they don't "look bad". Sadly this just ticks developers off that Microsoft doesn't appear to be motivated in the slightest to fix these issues... but I digress...

Comment: We have same problems with IE10. table-layout:fixed suddenly made all our tables a mile wide. We used to specify fixed widths on the th tags which has worked fine until IE10.

Answer (score 5):

My current workaround is the following style:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  table colgroup { display: table-row; }
  table colgroup col { display: table-cell; }
}
```

This makes the browser handle colgroup/col like tr/td and is similar to Teemu's suggestion (but without ugly html hacks). The media selector makes the css only visible to IE10+

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this, in IE9 actually. The only solution I found was, indeed, to put in a hidden dummy first row in the table:

```
<tr style="visibility: hidden"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Then, to get rid of the resulting gap, I apply a negative margin-top to the entire table. Not elegant, but it seems to get the job done.

Comment: I wonder a bit about this since we never had such problems in IE9 before - the example I wrote works in IE9 (and all other browsers except IE10).

Comment: It's tough to sort it out, because your HTML has a bunch of other, related errors in it. Feed your code through a validator, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I usually make like this

```
<colgroup width="100%"> // for table a whole
    <col width="50%">   // for each column
    <col width="50%">
</colgroup>
```

50% for 2 columns, 33% for 3, etc.

This worked for IE10.