# How to make fixed td in table with different screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have `form` containing `table` having 6 `columns`,i want to make the `td` of the `table` fixed with different screen size (laptop,ipad,phone,..etc),just a scrolling bar is added in different sizes.

```
<form id="NewCustFrm" style="border:2px solid rgb(16,29,73);">
    <table class="table2">
    <tr>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> First Name:</label></td>
    <td> 
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Last Name:</label></td>
    <td> 
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input  name="Last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Nick Name:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input  name="Nick_name" placeholder="Nick Name" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Facebook name:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
        <input  name="Facebook_name" placeholder="Facebook Name" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Email Address:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></span>
        <input  name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Birth Date:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class='input-group date' class='datetimepicker8'>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" class="Frm_Date" />
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Organization Name:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-building"></i></span>
        <input  name="Organization_Name" placeholder="Organization Name" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Celfone Number:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
        <input  name="Celfone_Number" placeholder="Celfone Number" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Landline Number:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
        <input  name="Landline_Number" placeholder="Landline Number" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Branch:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i></span>
        <input  name="Branch" placeholder="Branch" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Barangay:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
        <select class="SelectCust" name="BarangayName" id="BarangayName">
        <!--populate value using php-->
        <?php
             $stmt ="SELECT distinct Barangay_Name FROM Barangay";
             foreach ($conn->query($stmt) as $row) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['Barangay_Name'];?></option>
        <?php}?>
        </select>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Address:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
        <input  name="Address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Other Contact Name:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input  name="Contact_name" placeholder="Contact Name" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>                                   
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Contact Number:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
        <input  name="Contact_Number" placeholder="Contact Number" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Other Address:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
        <input  name="Other_Address" placeholder="Other Address" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Photo:</label></td>
    <td colspan="5"><!-- <label class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
        <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
        </label> -->
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Order Type:</label></td>
    <td colspan="5">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i></span>
        <select class="SelectCust" name="Type" id="Type">
        <option value="">Select Order Type</option>
        <option value="Cacao Beans">Cacao Beans</option>
        <option value="Bananas">Bananas</option>
        <option value="Coconuts">Coconuts</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Order Sub-Type:</label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Wet</label><input type="text" id="dist1" style="width:50px;" name="txtbox"> &nbsp;<label>Kg</label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Dry</label><input type="text" id="dist2" style="width:50px;" name="txtbox"> &nbsp;<label>Kg</label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Fermented</label><input type="text" id="dist3" style="width:50px;" name="txtbox"> &nbsp;<label>Kg</label></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label class="arrow-right"> Order Date:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class='input-group date' class='datetimepicker8' style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">
         <input type='text' class="form-control" class="Frm_Date" />
         <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
         </span>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><button id="Find" type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:55px;">Add Order</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and the CSS code

```
 table.table2
 {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap; 
 }
 table.table2 td
 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-break:break-all;
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should use attribute `width` setting its dimension in pixels.

For instance:

```
     table.table2 td
 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-break:break-all;
  width: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: it works when i set the width but the scrolling bar appeared in the explorer not at the bottom of the table,i mean that it went out of the form.

Comment: Then **col** tag may help you:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use media screen css like :

```css
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}



/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/**********
iPad 3
**********/

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */

@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

code working fine just you need to remove repetition of id.use class at place of repetitive id.
[click here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) you can see this link for better help.
in internet explorer show some problems.
see this link for related IE problem[here relative link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275199/ie10-table-layoutfixed-broken-if-colspan-is-used)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)